# How do I get values that are themselves not unique, but are linked to unique fields(in SQL)?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I can't give the actual table, but my problem is something like this:

Assuming that there is a table called Names with entries like these:

```
+--------------+
|  name | id   |
+--------------+
| Jack | 1001  |
| Jack | 1022  |
| John | 1010  |
| Boris | 1092 |
+--------------+
```

I need to select all the unique names from that table, and display them(only names, not ids). But if I do:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT name FROM Names;
```

Then it will return:

```
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| Jack  |
| John  |
| Boris |
+-------+
```

But as you can see in the table, the 2 people named "Jack" are different, since they have different ids. How do I get an output like this one:

```
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| Jack  |
| Jack  |
| John  |
| Boris |
+-------+
```

?

Assuming that some ids can or will be repeated(not marked primary key in question)
Also, in the question, the result will have 1 column and some number of rows(exact number **is** given, its 18,013). Is there a way to check if I have the right number of rows? I know I can use COUNT(), but while selecting the unique values I used GROUP BY, so using COUNT() would return the counts for how many names have that unique id, as in:

```
SELECT name FROM Names GROUP BY id;
```

---

```
+------------------+
| COUNT(name) | id |
+------------------+
| 2 | 1001         |
| 1 | 1022         |
| 1 | 1092         |
| 3 | 1003         |
+------------------+
```

So, is there something to help me verify my output?

Comment: your question is not clear  , what you explained is just a simple `select name FROM names` !

Comment: What is the set of columns that uniquely identify "the name"? Do a `GROUP BY` that set and select just `name` column. To count rows in table use `COUNT(1)` without any `WHERE` or `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by`:

```
select name
from names
group by name, id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the distinct persons with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, id
FROM names
```

and you can select from the above query only the names:

```
SELECT name
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT name, id
  FROM names
)
```